# AWS SDK for PHP: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am trying to send SNS messeges to android through web api.
Downloaded and installed the SDK from http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/php/

Got following error while running sample.php:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Common\Exception\InstanceProfileCredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. When you are not running inside of Amazon EC2, you must provide your AWS access key ID and secret access key in the "key" and "secret" options when creating a client or provide an instantiated Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface object. ([curl] 28: Connection timed out after 5016 milliseconds [url] http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws-php\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient.php:85 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aws-php\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Credentials\RefreshableInstanceProfileCredentials.php(52): Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient->getInstanceProfileCredentials() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\aws-php\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Credentials\AbstractRefreshableCredentials.php(54): Aws\Common\Credentials\Refreshable in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws-php\vendor\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\InstanceMetadata\InstanceMetadataClient.php on line 85
```

A little guidance on this topic will help me a lot

Comment: This means that you have not configured your credentials correctly. Please see [Providing Credentials to the SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html) from the AWS SDK for PHP User Guide.

Comment: I already configured the /.aws/credentials file with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY as mentioned here. Still it's not working

Comment: @JeremyLindblom I'm seriously struggling with the documentation on creating this one file. I am running an EC2 instance and via Putty attempted `sudo nano ~/.aws/credentials`, `sudo mkdir /.aws` + `cd /.aws` + `sudo nano credentials` - nothing wants to work and there's little information on the web. Any ideas?

Comment: Credential files are best used for local development environments. I would use IAM role credentials on EC2: https://web.archive.org/web/20150412020424/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/credentials.html

Comment: The issue, though, is that your HOME may _not_ be where you think it is when you are running PHP (i.e., see what `getenv('HOME')` returns in your app). You may need to move the file or call [`Credentials::fromIni()`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Aws/Common/Credentials/Credentials.php#L136) directly as a workaround. (However, like I said in the last comment, you should use IAM role credentials if you are hosted on EC2.)

Comment: For me the problem was that when I copied my MySQL database to a new server, the [BackWPup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/) encrypted value for the S3 access key no longer worked. I needed to go into BackWPup settings and provide the key again.

Answer (score 176):

In my case, I was using

```
return DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => AWS_REGION,
  'key' => AWS_KEY,
  'secret'  => AWS_SECRET
));
```

which used to be ok with `aws/aws-sdk-php` version 2.8.5 , but when composer automatically installed version 3.2.0, I got the error above. The problem is simply that I should've changed the way I made the call to

```
return DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => AWS_REGION,
  'credentials' => array(
    'key' => AWS_KEY,
    'secret'  => AWS_SECRET,
  )
));
```

as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#credential-profiles). Without changing the call, the *apache* php was falling back to looking for the `~/.aws/credentials` file using the HOME environment variable, which was empty. You can check its value by running `php -r 'var_dump(getenv("HOME"));'`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627029/aws-php-sdk-credentials-error-s) is a related post

Comment: This saved me a huge headache.

Comment: Wow, they managed to leave this incredibly important detail out of their SES guides...  Thank you

Comment: Ah - I see. Thats why it worked from the cli with my login, but not another!

Comment: Same solution if you use async-aws instead of aws sdk

Answer (score 33):

In my case I had to use **hard-coded credentials**

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'region' => REGION,
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => S3_KEY,
        'secret' => S3_SECRETE,
    ],
]);
```

See more details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html):

Comment: I was not understand before how to pass credentials, and here is your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You have to place the `.aws/credentials` file with your configuration in the home directory of the web service *usually `/var/www`) not in the home directory of the logged in user.

You can find what home directory you web service is using by running `echo getenv('HOME');` in a php file on your server.

Comment: `echo getenv('HOME');` return `null` to me using Docker php apache instance :(

Comment: make sure you don't just symlink it... needs to actually exist there in my case.

Comment: its still shows null even i not use docker and not symlink it

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to use a credentials file and got the same error, [this guy](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/887#issuecomment-174260184) on github pretty much nailed it:

> The credentials file should be in ini format but not have a .ini extension. It should have a 'default' section defined with your key and secret:

```
$ less ~/.aws/credentials

[default]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret
```

If you specified other section name instead of default, just add a `profile` key to the S3Client parameters:

```
[example]
aws_access_key_id = key
aws_secret_access_key = secret

$s3Client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'region' => $yourPreferredRegion,
    'profile' => 'example',
]);
```

> Using a credentials file or environment variables is the recommended way of providing credentials on your own server

And @Anti 's answer also helped me alot!

If you prefer the hard coded way, just follow @shadi 's answer.

Answer (score 6):

If it is laravel and aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel sdk then after configuring all step and defining key in .env file 
you have to drop config cache and rebuild it by following commands.

```
php artisan config:cache;
composer dump-autoload;
```

Answer (score 6):

assuming that the server is located on AWS EC2 (probably the same for ECS and elastic beanstalk) the "correct" way to handle this issue is not to store credentials at all.

instead, do this:

1. create an IAM role (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)
2. add relevant permissions to the role policy (in this case, send SNS msg)
3. assign the role to the EC2 instance (instance settings => Attach/Replace IAM Role)

this way you don't leave any sensitive data in your code.

Comment: This is the right way to go if your server/code is on AWS.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps:

1. Type `cd ~`
   By this you will go into the home directory.
2. `mkdir .aws`
3. `sudo vi .aws/credentials`
4. Write following lines and save the file.

   ```
   [default]
   aws_access_key_id = Your AWS Access Key

   aws_secret_access_key = Your AWS Secret Access Key
   ```

Comment: This works great if you're trying to use the AWS SDK in command-line scripts.

Comment: To save and exit vi - Hit esc and type :wq and then hit enter.
Or if you made a mistake while typing. To exit without saving vi - Hit esc and type :q! and then hit enter.

Answer (score 2):

This might be because the config file hasn't been published.

Be sure to publish the config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish  --provider="Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider"
```

To test this is the issue, just clear the config.

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If it works with the cache cleared, then this will be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (laravel 8, right after a few version upgrades) i had to change the "scripts" part of composer.json. Then after a "sail composer install" my AWS code worked again.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/composer.json

Answer (score -1):

You can try these lines:

$credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('key' , 'secret-key');

$s3 = new S3Client(['version' => 'latest','region'  => 'ap-south-1','credentials'=>$credentials]);