# connecting php on EC2 to a dynamoDB instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

needing to make an api on my EC2 instance of AWS to interact with dynamoDB.  GET, POST, PUT, DELETE all are required.
Things that are working:

- I have other php working on the same EC2 instance, so that seems ok
- I got composer.phar installed on the instance through my mac's
  terminal.
- I have some echo's from the php code working, so I know
  some of the requires and uses are ok

first bit of code in my php file:

```
<?php ...
...
$tableName = 'lab_instruments';
echo "past table name \n";
$assetNumber = 'OS014005';
$name = 'Billy';
$make = 'Hamilton';
$model = 'STARlet';
echo "past model \n";
$newItem = '
    {
        "assetNumber": "' . $assetNumber . '",
        "name": "' . $name . '",
        "make": "' . $make . '",
        "model": "' . $model . '"

    }
';
echo "newItem: " . $newItem . "\n";
$item = $marshaler->marshalJson($newItem);

$params = [
    'TableName' => 'lab_instruments',
    'Item' => [
        "assetNumber" => array('S' => $assetNumber),
        "name"=> array('S' => $name),
        "make" => array('S' => $make),
        "model" => array('S' => $model)
                ]    //$item
];

try {
    echo "in try \n";
    $result = $dynamodb->putItem($params);
    echo "Added item: $assetNumber - $name\n";

} catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
    echo "Unable to add item:\n";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

with @BradKent's help, I've got a bit further, and my newest echo to the browser is here:

> past table name past model newItem: { "assetNumber":
>   "OS014005", "name": "Billy", "make": "Hamilton", "model": "STARlet" }
>   in try  Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving
>   credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (Client error:
>   `GET
>   http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`
>   resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:  Aws\Credentials{closure}(Array)
>
> ## 1 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(2, Array, Array) #2
>
> /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(61):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() #3
>   /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(96):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run() #4 /var/www in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php
>   on line 79

I'm very grateful to have gotten further, but not sure how to address this issue adding the new item

Comment: have you looked in the error logs?  Add this to your script to output errors directly:  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @BradKent, I'm new enough that it hadn't occurred to me, so I looked, repeating failure is:  _PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\\Sdk' not found in /var/www/html/Asmt3/addInstr.php on line 22_

Comment: for the reference of future browsers, I found the log via this command in the terninal:  `sudo tail /var/log/httpd/error_log`

Comment: can you confirm that the AWS sdk is in the vendor directory?  and that you've installed v3 of the the SDK?  You [installed via composer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html)?

Comment: `[...html]$ ls vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php ==>

composer.json  LICENSE.md  NOTICE.md  src` and I followed the instructions at _http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/installation.html_ which call for version 2.x

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, `$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);`  is v3
(use v3 unless you have a reason to be using v2)  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/

Comment: Have you seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400563/aws-sdk-for-php-error-retrieving-credentials-from-the-instance-profile-metadata