# AWS S3 cURL timed out

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

In general, AWS S3 works fine in my web. However, I keep getting randomly these errors when downloading:

```
Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: Operation timed out after {>1000} milliseconds with 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))
```

Why? How can I prevent these errors from happening?

I am using AWS SDK PHP v3.

Comment: You can't, the internet is not 100% reliable.  You can do something like retry once, then go on to other error handling.

Comment: can't you just set a higher CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ? https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html

Comment: Increasing the timeout is unlikely to help, since this question is about the **instance metadata service** (which isn't exactly "the Internet.")  If this is a `t`-family instance, how is your CPU credit balance?  How is your workload relative to the instance's capabilities?  Is this a new problem?

Comment: Check if the response here helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400563/aws-sdk-for-php-error-retrieving-credentials-from-the-instance-profile-metadata/43250859

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot No, CPU credit balance is not a problem.

Comment: There isn't a good reason for this to happen, unless you're overloading the metadata service with excessive requests -- that service runs on the same host (hypervisor) as your instance.  It literally right there.  But, I seem to recall some vague documentation about overloading it.  Obviously, it's capacity isn't infinite, but I'd expect it to be adequate... and I would also expect the temporary credentials to be cached by the SDK, though I have spent very little time looking at the php SDK

Comment: Mention of SDKs using metadata service: 
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html

Answer (score 4):

if are you using a Credential like below

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',
        'key' => "AKIAJAAAXXYASASASASDSUAG66MA",
        'secret'  => "8sZyAAAAXUSuUK3FJSDFSDS&D*SDSJFSFShjssa7Fx+GS9"
    )
]);
```

then change to like this

```
   $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => "AKIAJAAAXXYASASASASDSUAG66MA",
            'secret'  => "8sZyAAAAXUSuUK3FJSDFSDS&D*SDSJFSFShjssa7Fx+GS9"
        )
    ]);
```

Comment: note they've changed it from 'key' and 'secret' to 'aws_access_key_id' and 'aws_secret_access_key' respectively

Comment: if you want to be 100% certain, create a new instance of \Aws\Credentials\Credentials for the value of 'credentials'.  e.g.: 'credentials' => new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('YOURACCESSKEY','YOURSECRET')